# How is this superposition-of-waves argument correct?

Tags: waves, superposition, linear-systems

In the fifth edition of *Optics* Hecht shows that a superposition of wavefunctions (functions that satisfy the wave equation) is a solution to the wave equation. No problem there. He then claims

> What this means is that when two separate waves arrive at the same place in space wherein they overlap, they will simply add to (or subtract from) one another without permanently destroying or disrupting either wave. ***The resulting disturbance at each point in the region of overlap is the algebraic sum of the individual constituent waves at that location***.

What? How does that mathematical property of wave functions imply that physical property of waves? To me this is somewhat analogous to saying that the fact that forces can be added means that the force on particle A due to particle B and particle C is the force on particle A due to particle B (without particle C) plus the force on particle A due to particle C (without particle B); not so.

Answer (score 4):

From the OP's comments to the question,

> That a wavefunction describes a wave doesn't in any obvious way imply that a superposition of wavefunctions describes the "superposition" of the constituent waves [...] I'm surprised that people don't see that what Hecht wrote ostensibly doesn't constitute a valid argument [...] So in conclusion the argument is garbage but that's just how physicists reason?

Let me save you some trouble.  No mathematical reasoning ever implies (in the sense of deductive reasoning) anything about the physical world, **ever**, under any circumstances. The reason for this is that physics is inductive and empirical, not deductive and axiomatic.

In physics, we observe phenomena, formulate mathematical models of those phenomena, and then test our models to see if and how accurately they describe nature.  If their accuracy over a particular range of conditions is reliably and repeatably demonstrated, then we say that they are adequate (for that range of conditions). If a model makes a prediction and that prediction fails to be accurate, then the model needs to be improved or replaced.

If physical waves are accurately modeled by a solution to the wave equation, then they must obey the superposition principle by definition of the word "accurately."  Put a different way, waves which do not obey the superposition principle are not (by definition) accurately modeled by solutions to the wave equation.

---

At least in a theoretical sense, you must understand that the best you can do is play with *models*, not physical phenomena.  If I were sitting in on a basic lecture on the theory ocean waves, then I would understand the word "wave" to be shorthand for "a mathematical function which obeys the equations written on the board and which accurately models the behavior of ocean waves under the conditions relevant to this lecture."  I would not expect the long version because it is aggressively, pointlessly pedantic.

If I raised my hand and said, "but professor, water is made of molecules so the wave equation doesn't apply and nothing you say actually implies anything about the physical world" then I would expect her to roll her eyes so hard that she could see her own brain.

---

> Suppose that a binary operation on two wavefunctions $f(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ that isn't addition satisfied the wave equation. Why wouldn't $f(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ be the resultant wave? I'm trying to see what's so special about addition. It seems that the postulate being used in what Hecht shows is that if $f(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ for some binary operation $f$ on wavefunctions, then $f(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ describes the resultant wave.

This is quite different from your original question.  Consider some $\psi$ which obeys the wave equation, and which is supported on two distinct regions $R_A$ and $R_B$ with $R_A\cap R_B = \emptyset$.  Then it should be obvious that we can write $\psi = \psi_A + \psi_B$, where $\psi_A$ is supported only on $R_A$ and $\psi_B$ is supported only on $R_B$.

Having done this, the linearity of the (homogeneous) wave equation then implies that we can evolve $\psi$ forward in time by evolving $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ separately, and then adding the results.  The interpretation is that any solution to the wave equation can be decomposed into parts which evolve independently of one another, and the full solution is obtained via superposition.

Put differently, if the wave operator is given by
$$L[\psi] = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - c^2 \nabla^2\right)\psi$$
then $L[\psi_1+\psi_2]=L[\psi_1]+L[\psi_2]$.  This is what is meant  when one says that the wave equation is linear.

Comment: Nicely said. A moderator is likely to delete the lengthy comment stream from which you have drawn the OP’s quotes. So you may want to mention that they came from responses to comments on the question, not from the question itself.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, thanks. I've edited in that clarification.

Comment: When I'm talking about implying something about the physical phenomena I'm just using sloppy language: I'm referring to *my understanding* of the model being used, not the actual physical phenomena.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy I’m afraid I don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @J.Murray Well I think I've elucidated the source of confusion in a comment under Cort Ammon's post if you're still interested in trying to help me

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy I have made an edit to address that question.

Comment: @J.Murray I follow your reasoning but it's such a bizarre argument to me that I'll have to scrutinize it for a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Murray I can't accept the answer, however, because it doesn't address why Hecht's reasoning is correct, rather you gave a different argument.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Do as you'd like.  But my reasoning is that the linearity of the wave equation implies that if you decompose a solution of the wave equation into a sum of parts, then those parts evolve independently and the full solution is obtained by adding them back together.  That's exactly what Hecht said.

Comment: Why are you talking about two distinct regions? It seems to me that that confuses the issue.

Comment: @G.Smith I mentioned it because Hecht refers to "two separate waves" arriving at some location and then interfering.  I'm not sure what that means if not that the disturbance was localized to two separated regions.

Comment: But where they interfere they *aren’t* separated.

Comment: @G.Smith Right.  I'm saying they start separated (at which point the total disturbance is trivially the sum of the two parts), then evolve forward in time until they aren't anymore, at which point the total wave *remains* the sum of the individual parts because of the linearity of the wave equation.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it backwards.  Instead of thinking of the mathematical wave properties as somehow implying a physical property, turn it around.  **If a system does not exhibit the behaviors defined by mathematical waves, we simply don't think of the physical system as a wave.**

What has happened is, over the years, we have found some systems are *astonishingly* symmetric to the mathematical concept of a wave.  Every time we construct a new experiment which depends on the mathematical behavior of waves, we find that the physical system yields the corresponding wave-like behavior.  If it didn't, we would cease to model that system as a wave, and we'd start using other models.

This happens, for instance, in supersonic flow situations.  The air certainly behaves wave-like in the subsonic regions, but as it transitions into supersonic flow, all of those nice wave equations break down in what we call a "shock."  So we treat the pressure of these gasses as a wave up until it goes supersonic, then we say "well... it's no longer wave like, so let's stop treating it as a wave."

Comment: Thanks, but that was already very clear to me. I think the disconnect is simply that there's an underlying set of postulates of the theory that I'm not familiar with. Maybe physicists tend to be very ad-hoc and have theories that don't readily lend themselves to postulization. If you could write out the underlying assumptions of the theory of waves we could probably get somewhere, otherwise it might be hopeless. I'm including @JohnRennie because this would be my response to his comment.

Comment: The underlying assumption of the theory of linear waves is that they satisfy the linear wave equation, and that the mathematics of that model describes the physics correctly in terms of agreeing with experiments. There’s nothing mysterious that physicists are keeping secret.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy The undelying assumption is that $\ddot u = c^2\nabla^2 u$, which is really just a formal way of saying that the forces on an element in the wave-like thing are a particularly simple function of position, such as the 1 dimensional equation F=-kx that we find true in springs.  The other results, such as linearity derive from that equation.  And it just happens to be a simple enough equation that we see it quite a lot!

Comment: The real peculiarity is what Newton and Leibniz discovered: for some reason it's particularly effective to model our world as a system of second order differential equations.  And, for some reason, at the root of it all, it seems that we don't need a third order differential equation, and that quite often a linear differential equation is "good enough" for the predictions we need to make.

Comment: @G.Smith Suppose that a binary operation on two wavefunctions $f(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ that isn't addition satisfied the wave equation. Why wouldn't $f(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ be the resultant wave? I'm trying to see what's so special about addition. It seems that the postulate being used in what Hecht shows is that if $f(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ for some binary operation $f$ on wavefunctions, then $f(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ describes the resultant wave.

Comment: @CortAmmon Please see my comment above

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy So the special behavior that matters is that the operator is linear.  Addition is one such linear operator.  Why we use addition is a matter of convenience.  Any linear operator would do, if it modeled the behavior we see in real life.  However, addition is a fundamental, simple, and powerful operator.   If given a choice, we use addition as our operator because it makes our lives easier.  We only use more exotic operators when there is a property of addition which doesn't seem to hold in the real world.

Comment: This bias  is so strong, in fact, that in mathematics, we typically phrase the definition of "linearity" to be defined with respect to "addition" and we redefine the precise meaning of addition to suit the problem (at the abstract algebra level).  Of course, one of the reasons that real number addition is so strong is that it's part of the definition of the *field* of real numbers.  If you can model things as a field, you get a LOT of power.  Why not gain that power if it works?  Why make life harder?